# Undefined variable: categories (View: resources\views\product\create.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to get categories in products/create page but it says:  (View: \resources\views\product\create.blade.php) how to resolve it?

controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::with('category')->distinct()->get();

    return view('product.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

blade file:

```
 <select name="select">
     @foreach($categories as $category)
         <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $title }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```

category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'category_product');
}
```

product model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_product');
}
```

these are routes:

```
|        |           | GET|HEAD                   | password/reset/{token}     | password.reset          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | product                    | product.store           | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | product                    | product.index           | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | product/create             | product.create          | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create                          | web          |
|        | DELETE    | product/{product}          | product.destroy         | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@destroy                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | product/{product}          | product.show            | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@show                            | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | product/{product}          | product.update          | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@update                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | product/{product}/edit     | product.edit            | App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@edit                            | web          |
|        | POST      | register                   |                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                   | register                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
```

Comment: What is the relationship `Category::with('category')`? Can you show this relationship?

Comment: In your index function you are returning to index page. Where is the create function that returns to the create page?

Comment: @programmer0001  $categories = Category::with('category')->distinct()->get();   please explain this line properly.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon now i write it into create function and now it says Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\Category].

Comment: your wrong in this blade `product\create.blade.php` so show us the method in your controller that goes to this view

Comment: i editied my question

Comment: now error is:  Call to undefined relationship [category] on model [App\Category].

Comment: that because this `Category::with('category')` change it to this `Category::with('categories')`

Comment: still same error

Comment: can you put your error message

Comment: ooh you don't have `categories` function in your model so make it just like this:
`$categories = Category::distinct()->get();`

Comment: plz show the complete function code

Comment: `public function create(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::distinct()->get();

    return view('product.create', compact('categories'));
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to retrieve categories list you just need to change your code like this, that way you will get correct all categories existed

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
     $categories = Category::distinct()->get(); // or Category::all();

     return view('product.create', compact('categories'));
}
```

if you curious with your error, you dont need with , this method used if you want to retrieve with the relationship needed (eager loading)

based on your blade, you don't need that since you want retrieve the category lists